# AJAX Pagination adding data insted of replacing data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I Have a working **PHP Based** Pagination onto which i am adding ajax to improve page load.

my problem is ajax is adding whole **navigation page**(to which navigation is made through pagination link)  to **current page content**.

and to be specific data added is whole navigation page in a **div** used for **content display.** which should be like **replacing current page** content   with **navigation page** content.

my pagination is in div with **id="pagination"** with ul li.
my repeating page content is in div with **id="temp"**.

my ajax code

```
    $(function(){
$('#pagination ul li a').click(function (ev) {
ev.preventDefault();    
$('div#temp').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
});
```

and my navigatin link structure in pagination is like this

```
echo " <li><a href='is-test.php?page=$nextpage'>Next&raquo;&raquo;</a></li> ";
```

please tell me how i can make ajax to replace data insted of adding data.

Thanks.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your PHP page.

Comment: I'd also like to add your pagination system looks yucky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally `.load()` should replace the contents of `div#temp`. But you can solve this by: following:

```
$('div#temp').empty();

$('div#temp').load($(this).attr('href'));
```

or

```
 $('div#temp').load($(this).attr('href') + '#temp');
```

Comment: or maybe `$('div#temp').val('');`

Comment: @Norse You can't use `val()` to `div`. `.val()` used for `input`.

Comment: dosent help is there a way to code like this $('div#temp').load(($this #temp).attr('href'));
so that it will only replace temp with temp not with whole page

Comment: got it $('#temp').load($(this).attr("href")+' #temp'); thanks anyways.